# Replace numbers in countdown JS

Tags: javascript, html

Im sitting in a project, where i would like to display images instead of the numbers. But i can't figure out if it is possible in a JS countdown.

At the moment my code looks like this, but i don't get any results.

Hope somebody can help me?

```
<div id="countdown" onload="myFunction"></div>
<div id="newcountdown"></div>

CountDownTimer('02/19/2017 10:1 AM', 'countdown');
CountDownTimer('02/20/2017 10:1 AM', 'newcountdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}

(function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("2", "W3Schools");
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = res;}
```

Comment: divs do not have onload and your myFunction is not correctly executed

Comment: Yeah, you can try to put the js to the bottom of the <body> so it'll run on page load.

Comment: No need. The code runs if the lines with myFunction is removed

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers - but i still got a problem. Because i like to put in something else than numbers - text or images? I tried to make the changes you told me to.. https://jsfiddle.net/mbek0f96/

Comment: See my answer... You need to change `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';` and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to

1. remove the line with the replace
2. change

   ```
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
   ```

to

```
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = getImg(days) + 'days ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += getImg(hours) + 'hrs ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += getImg(minutes) + 'mins ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += getImg(seconds) + 'secs';
```

and have

```
function getImg(num) {
  var digits = String(num).split(""), text="";
  for (var i=0;i<digits.length;i++) {
    text += '<img src="'+digits[i]+'.gif" />';
  }
  return text;
}
```

and have 0.gif, 1.gif ... 9.gif on your server

```js
function getImg(num) {
      var digits = String(num).split(""), text="";
      for (var i=0;i<digits.length;i++) {
        text += '<img alt="'+digits[i]+'" src="'+digits[i]+'.gif" />';
      }
      return text;
    }



CountDownTimer('02/19/2017 10:1 AM', 'countdown');
CountDownTimer('02/20/2017 10:1 AM', 'newcountdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= getImg(days) + 'days '
                 + getImg(hours) + 'hrs '
                 + getImg(minutes) + 'mins '
                 + getImg(seconds) + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
<div id="newcountdown"></div>
```

Comment: A smoother one would be to have 000-00:00:00 already as gifs and change the src of each.